# error TS2339: JavaScript to Typescript error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, syntax-error

---

> ERROR in src/app/dashboard.component.ts(49,15): error TS2339: Property
>   'style' does not exist on type 'Element'.
>   src/app/dashboard.component.ts(50,16): error TS2339: Property
>   'textContent' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

---

This works as a javascript function, but the above are the errors I get when I try to use this in typescript. I have tried changing var to let and adding . any other suggestions? Thanks.

**dashboard.ts**

```
var w = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var button = document.getElementById('randomize');
var image = w.children; // inner elements, your quotes divs

// a function to hide all divs
var hideDivs = function(divs) {
  for (var div of divs) {
    div.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

hideDivs(image); // hide all initially

// on click
button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * image.length); // get random index
  hideDivs(image); // hide all quotes
  image[rnd].style.display = 'block'; // show random quote
  event.target.textContent = 'Click one more time!'; // set button text. event.target is the button you've clicked
})
```

**dashboard.html**

```
  <div id="wrapper">
  <div class="image" img scr='../../assets/mood.jpg'></div>
  <div class="image" img scr='../../assets/mood.jpg'></div>
  <div class="image" img scr='../../assets/mood.jpg'></div>
  <div class="image" img scr='../../assets/mood.jpg'></div>
  <div class="image" img scr='../../assets/mood.jpg'></div>
</div>
<button id='randomize'>Next</button>
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `target` is typed as `EventTarget`, and an element of `image` which is a `HTMLCollection` is typed as `Element`. Both of the properties you want to access are defined on `HTMLElement`. The simplest thing you can do is to use a type assertion to tell the compiler that in your case both of these are actually `HTMLElement`

```
// on click
button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * image.length); // get random index
    hideDivs(image); // hide all quotes

    (image[rnd] as HTMLElement).style.display = 'block'; // show random quote
    (event.target as HTMLElement).textContent = 'Click one more time!'; // set button tqext. event.target is the button you've clicked
})
```

Yo might also want to type `hideDivs` correctly as well :

```
// a function to hide all divs
const hideDivs = function (divs : HTMLCollection) {
    for (var div of divs) {
        (div as HTMLElement).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: Update `hideDivs()` function as well. ;)

Comment: @Durga true, that did not cause an error (since divs is implicitly typed as `any`) . Updated the answer :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. That compiles successfully but now all divs appear and the error within the console.log is "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null"

Comment: @KatieKennedy strange... the onlu place you use `children` is `w.children`, i did not touch that .. where does `w` come from ? are you sure it is not undefined ?

Comment: w is used to get the ID of the wrapper enclosing the images.               var w = document.getElementById('wrapper');

Comment: I think its the .children method that isnt working. Is there another way to write this in typescript?

Comment: @KatieKennedy children should work fine. When is your js executed ? It should executre after docuemtn load. here is a jsfiddle with your code that works https://jsfiddle.net/z4vo5u5d/5163/